# SSL alternative for secure handshake?

Tags: javascript, security, ssl, iframe

1. I'm curious if there's any way that a server can validate a client without knowing that the client is entirely "friendly" code that isn't monitoring 1) the user's input or 2) network requests.

The only way I could conceive of this is if browsers have a built-in, secure, isolated shell / scope that can hash and send data (which can be verified with a complimenting server unhashing / lookup script).

---

2. Is there any browser-supported (non-DOM) input/hashing method that can **also** be installed on the server to identify the authenticity or user input? I want to avoid Chrome Extensions and potential keylogging in general, but I'm not sure any browser supports this feature.

Thanks

---

EDIT

I think some form of 2-step auth in a separate window would be the closest, but I don't have SSL, and I don't like the presentation of random "popup" windows

Comment: I recommend to move this question to security.stackexchange.org.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking for a proof that the data entered into a form are neither manipulated nor generated by malicious software. But you (as operator of the server) don't have control of the client.

This is impossible as long as you don't have control of the client because it is impossible to distinguish user generated data from software generated data on the network level, and that's all you get at the server. Even the output generated by a browser extension can be faked.

> I think some form of 2-step auth would be the closest

2FA is relevant for authentication of the client only and provides no way of making user generated data tamper resistant.

> SSL alternative for secure handshake?

SSL only protects the transport and does not prevent modification of the user input within a malicious browser extension or similar. It also does not protect against malicious man in the middle on the clients machine (i.e. [Superfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfish) or similar).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea I'm concerned that there's no isolated environment where keyloggers can't capture input in a browser, except for an SSL served environment. I feel like there should be a way to handoff auth and keypresses to the device/browser (like iPhone touchID)

Comment: I'm worried about man in the middle interceptions, and don't want a user to expose his password to the global environment, given that he may have content scripts running that could be monitoring his input

Comment: @neaumusic: In the current form the question does not contain a clear picture of what you are worried about. Man in the middle can do different things than man in the browser which is also different to generic malware on the system etc. Maybe you should start by describing the original problem you are trying to solve and not the way you want to solve it (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). And a better site for this kind of questions is probably security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I can help clarify if you ask specific questions. Man in the middle is someone reading your password before the server receives it. How is there no native way to authenticate a user without potential keyloggers or `<input>` inspecting code stealing every password and email you ever entered. I'm just supposed to stay up-to-date with Adblock and other extensions?? SSL isn't secure if the user has permissioned extensions installed, right? The browser and OS should have hooks for sending authenticated requests in private, rather than reflected on the dom, but I don't know what these are

Comment: @neaumusic: Your last comment sounds like you are asking only about how to secure the authentication part. The original question instead sounded like you are asking about securing user input in general. 2FA or even one factor where the factor is a separate device ("to have" and not "to know") might help with the first but not with the second.